# Can azure logic app can run multiple HTTP request on single trigger?

Tags: azure, http, azure-logic-apps, azure-scheduler, azure-triggers

I need to make 6 HTTP request using trigger in one logic resource only. How can I make multiple HTTP request from logic app. Also Azure logic app showing error "This session has timed out. To see the latest run status, navigate to the runs history blade."

All the http request should be independent of each other. 
If any documents is available for this please share.

Answer (score 0):

Every logic app workflow **starts with a trigger**, which fires when a specific event happens, or when new available data meets specific criteria.

**Each time that the trigger fires**, the Logic Apps engine creates a logic app instance that runs the actions in the workflow.

For HTTP trigger , follow the doc **[Call, trigger, or nest workflows with HTTP endpoints in Azure Logic Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-http-endpoint#targetText=Sign%20in%20to%20the%20Azure,trigger%20to%20your%20logic%20app.)**

Answer (score 0):

YES.  This is a very basic pattern.

How?  Well, you just do.  If it's exactly 6 calls, you can use 6 HTTP Connectors.  If it's variable, you have to loop on whatever incoming set you have and put the HTTP Connector in the loop.

All outbound request are independent of each other.